# Dart add new Stream to stream group

Tags: dart, stream

I want to make several periodic REST API calls and merge all the responses into one single stream. This is possible with StreamGroup, but is it possible to merge a new stream to the already existing stream at runtime? Let's say I have two periodic streams that I merge into one stream with StreamGroup. How can I add/merge a new `stream.periodic` (for example `getC()`) to the already existing Stream `stream` *after it was created* (so after `StreamGroup.merge(streamList)`) ?

```dart
import 'package:async/async.dart' show StreamGroup;

// ... 
Stream<dynamic> stream;
var streamList = <Stream>[];

// ...

void addPeriodicCallToA({Duration period}) {
    streamList.add(Stream<dynamic>.periodic(period, (x) async {
      return await getA();
    }));
  }

// ...

void addPeriodicCallToB({String symbol, Duration period}) {
    streamList.add(Stream<dynamic>.periodic(period, (x) async {
      return await getB(symbol: symbol);
    }));
  }

// ...

addPeriodicCallToA(period: Duration(seconds: 1));
addPeriodicCallToA(period: Duration(symbol: 'yoloandswaglol', seconds: 2));
stream = StreamGroup.merge(streamList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully tested this out yet, but have you tried just adding the streams directly to the `StreamGroup` like this:

```
import 'package:async/async.dart' show StreamGroup;

// ... 
StreamGroup streamGroup = StreamGroup(); //<-- create StreamGroup
Stream<dynamic> stream;

// ...

void addPeriodicCallToA({Duration period}) {
    // Add to streamGroup
    streamGroup.add(Stream<dynamic>.periodic(period, (x) async {
      return await getA();
    }));
  }

// ...

void addPeriodicCallToB({String symbol, Duration period}) {
    // Add to streamGroup
    streamGroup.add(Stream<dynamic>.periodic(period, (x) async {
      return await getB(symbol: symbol);
    }));
  }

// ...

addPeriodicCallToA(period: Duration(seconds: 1));
addPeriodicCallToA(period: Duration(symbol: 'yoloandswaglol', seconds: 2));
stream = streamGroup.stream; // <-- set to stream object
```